# XSLT 2.0 or XSLT3.0: Group and Merge nodes together based on same value

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have been having trouble getting desired output while transforming below xml. I had posted a couple of similar questions in the last few days. The solution that I received gets the desired output for the source XML that I provided in those questions. However, my source XML has slightly changed since I posted my last question and here is the final version of the source XML.

**Source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>71354</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>520.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>900.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
        <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-08-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>800.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>410.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
        <Misc>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <BonusAmount>600.00</BonusAmount>
        </Misc>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

**Requirement**

- In source XML, the value for element `<UniqueID>` under a `<Worker>` node will not be repeated in the source xml
- There are **4** different dates in the whole document, such as `2023-10-10-07:00` `2023-10-09-07:00` `2023-10-08-07:00` `2023-10-06-07:00`. Since my final output should be grouped based on `<Date>` and there are **4** different dates on my source xml, my expected result should have **4** `<EmployeeRecords>`nodes and each `<Employee>` node should hold unique `<Date>` element corresponding to `<Worker>`
- In source XML, `<Worker>`nodes may or may not contain `<Misc>` nodes. Any `Worker` node that doesn't have `Misc` node should be copied under all `EmployeeRecords` nodes in the expected output
- In source XML, `<Misc>` nodes under a specific `<Worker>` node may have different
  `<Date>` and `<BonusAmount>` from other `Misc` nodes under that specific `Worker` node.
- In source XML, it is possible to have more than one `Misc` nodes with same `Date` under `Worker` node for a `UniqueID` e.g. `UniqueID` `71354` has two `<Misc>` nodes with same `Date` but with different `BonusAmount`

**Current XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/Workers">
        
        <Employees>
            <xsl:variable name="undated" select="Worker[not(Misc)]"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker/Misc" group-by="Date">
                <EmployeeRecords>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$undated"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="..[not(Misc)]/(* except Misc)"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <Employee>
                            <xsl:for-each select=".">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="..[Misc]/(* except Misc)"/>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Employee>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </EmployeeRecords>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Employees>
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <EmployeeRecords>
        <Worker> <!-- name of this element should be <Employee> instead of <Worker> -->
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker> <!-- name of this element should be <Employee> instead of <Worker> -->
            <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>71354</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc> <!-- Misc node that follow this node should be copied under the parent <Employee> node because of same Unique ID 71354 and same <Date> -->
                <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>71354</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>  <!-- This Misc node should be copied above because of same Unique ID 71354 and same <Date> -->
                <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>520.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>600.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeRecords>
    <EmployeeRecords>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>71354</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>900.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>410.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeRecords>
    <EmployeeRecords>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeRecords>
    <EmployeeRecords>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
        </Worker>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-08-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>800.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeRecords>
</Employees>
```

Expected Output

**Issue**

- Name of element  that doesn't have `Misc` node should have been `<Employee>` instead of `Worker`. I tried changing element name but the result is incorrect because of variable `$undated` declaration.
- Currently two `Employee` nodes are showing in my current output for `UniqueID` with value `71354` so `Misc` node under a `Worker` node for same `UniqueID` and `Date` should be copied under  one `Employee` parent node.

****Expected Output****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <EmployeeRecords>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>71354</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>520.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>600.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeRecords>
    <EmployeeRecords>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>71354</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>900.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-09-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>410.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeRecords>
    <EmployeeRecords>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeRecords>
    <EmployeeRecords>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>67896</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>400.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>230.00</BonusAmount>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>12465</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>500.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <BonusAmount>430.00</BonusAmount>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <UniqueID>45679</UniqueID>
            <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
            <Misc>
                <Date>2023-10-08-07:00</Date>
                <BonusAmount>800.00</BonusAmount>
            </Misc>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeRecords>
</Employees>
```

The application that I'm using supports both XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 3.0 so I'm tagging the question to both XSLT 2.0 and 3.0

Any help is appreciated here to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: I think your problem is too complex to be suitable as a question, maybe you should reframe it with a very simple problem (that is basically the same but without the fluff).
Its better to ask a question about how to achieve some general goal with a simple example, rather than ask people to debug your complex code for you.